# How to add logic to my route when using directory handler in Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have added the following code for my route:

```
server.route([
{ method: 'GET', path: '/{file*}',
    config:{
     handler: {
        directory: {
            path: 'public',
            listing: true,
            index: true
        }
    }, 
auth: { mode: 'try' }, 
plugins: { 'hapi-auth-cookie': { redirectTo: false } } 
} } ]);
```

Although this does serve my purpose of serving all the static content, I still don't really understand where to add the rest of the logic that I would have added in a handler function, had there been one.
But the presence of the directory handler wouldn't let me have a function. So I want to know where to add the rest of the logic for this route.

Edit:
I tried adding the plugin Electric Fence:

```
var ElectricFence = require('electricfence'); 
var options = { 
    path: 'public', 
    url: '/menu/{param*}', 
    listing: true, 
    index: false, 
    cache: 3600000 }; 
server.pack.register([{plugin: ElectricFence, options: options}]);
server.route({ 
    method: 'GET', 
    path: '/menu/{param*}', 
    handler: menuget });
```

But this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What sort of logic do you want to implement? All options for serving files are mentioned here: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files

Comment: I don't want to use my GET route to just serve some static files. I want it to store some data in the database and also want to start a session for the user the moment they hit this route. How do I implement this all if there's no handler function, that accepts a request and returns a reply?

Comment: https://github.com/wraithgar/electricfence

Electric Fence seems to be providing the kind of functionality I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Could you post the code you use for the electric fence integration? Maybe we could figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the code instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: You dont have to add a route if you have specified the same in the plugin

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm pretty new to node.js, so I'm not sure if I'm getting it right.
So what I can make out about what ElectricFence does is that it allows you to have a handler while serving the files too. So if I don't add a route, how do I add the handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Path = require('path');
    const Hapi = require('hapi');
    const Inert = require('inert');

    const server = new Hapi.Server({
        connections: {
            routes: {
                files: {
                    relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
                }
            }
        }
    });

    server.connection({ port: 3000 });

    server.register(Inert, () => {});

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        config: {
            validate: {
                query: {
                    id: require('joi').number()
                }
            },
            handler: {
                directory: {
                    path: '.',
                    redirectToSlash: true,
                    index: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    server.ext('onRequest', function(req, reply) {
        for(var key in req.query){
            if(key) {
                //some database and session logic goes here
                console.log(req.query);
            }
        }
        reply.continue();
    });

    server.start((err) => {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
    });
```